# Sidekiq ActionMailer working in development but not i produciton (using mailgun)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sidekiq, mailgun

I have set up Sidekiq to send an email on sign up.

The process works fine in development mode however in production it seems like my smtp settings (or something else) is not working, when i use sidekiq (sendt to redis).

Is there a gotcha to using sidekiq to send mails via Mailgun?

This is my create user action:

```
def create 
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.roles << Role.find_by_role("member")
    @user.subdomain = @user.subdomain.downcase
    @user.generate_token(:confirm_email_token)
    @user.confirm_email_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    if @user.save
        UserMailer.delay.new_user(@user.id)

        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for registering."
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

And this is my mailer:

```
def new_user(user_id)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  mail :to => @user.email, :subject => "Welcome to Theatrical.co"
end
```

In development this works fine. However in produciton this is not working. I get this error messege:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
```

It seems to be related to Mailgun not accepting redis or sidekiq to send mail.

Is there some secret setting i need to chenge?

Answer (score 0):

You must be authorized to use a mail server for relaying .Unauthorized users will receive the "Relaying Denied" error. confirm that user has sufficient permission to send mail